# Multiple JavaFX TextArea

Tags: textarea, javafx, javafx-2

I am using JavaFX and I am having a problem with using multiple TextArea's. I set all 3 of them as editable however I can only click in and edit the first one. I can hit SHIFT-TAB to go backwards to the 3rd one then the 2nd one. After that I can click on them all. I'm not too sure what is going on and any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe.  For the sample program below I can click and edit any of the 3 displayed TextAreas without having to first SHIFT-TAB.  I am using JavaFX Version: 2.1.0-beta-b10 on Windows7.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultiTextAreas extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("JavaFX Version: " + System.getProperties().get("javafx.runtime.version"));
    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) layout.getChildren().add(new TextArea("Area " + i));
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out the problem. In order to click between the area's you have to click in the very upper left corner. I wasn't doing that before. I was just clicking anywhere. I don't know why you have to click in the upper left corner but at least I know its working now.

Comment: On my machine I can click anywhere in any of the TextArea controls to switch the focus to the clicked on control.  You are encountering an environment specific bug, which you could log with a sample program and your full system configuration in the JavaFX bug tracker http://javafx-jira.kenai.com (signup required, but anybody can signup).